# angular-mock and node.js conflicting when running grunt-typescript on the "module" global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, typescript

I'm using grunt-typescript, which is compiling all my *.ts files. I'm using both angular-mocks.d.ts and node.d.ts, however I'm referencing them separately in my actual ts files. I'm using angular-mocks only for jasmine testing, and I'm using node in my server.ts file.
**The problem** I'm having is that, even though they're referenced separately, when they are compiled within grunt-typescript, it seems to dump them together somehow so that their two different definitions of "module" end up conflicting. If I build my server.ts file by itself using tsc (which references node.d.ts), it builds fine. The two should never actually coincide and so for me isn't *really* a conflict except it's becoming one in grunt-typescript which seems to dump all the *.d.ts files together as it's compiling. I assume this is because it's building all of my *.ts files together and so ends up pulling the *.d.ts files together into a common space.

The error I get:

> c:/node/bills/typings/node/node.d.ts(37,13):
>   error TS2134: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'module' must be of type '(...modules: any[]) => any', but here has type '{ exports: any; require(id: string): any; id: string; filename: string; loaded: boolean; parent: any; children: any[]; }'.

**angular-mocks.d.ts** "module" definition:

```
declare var module: (...modules: any[]) => any;
```

**node.d.ts** "module" definition:

```
declare var module: {
    exports: any;
    require(id: string): any;
    id: string;
    filename: string;
    loaded: boolean;
    parent: any;
    children: any[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working for me. I split my test .ts files into a separate typescript run. That causes it not to run together my test declarations and my runtime declarations. With those separated, the module ambient declarations no longer conflict.

```
    typescript: {
        options:
        {
            target: 'es5', //or es3
            base_path: '',
            sourcemap: true,
            declaration: false
        },
        server: {
            src: ['*.ts']
        },
        test: {
            src: ['test/*.ts']
        }
    },

    watch: {
        files: ['*.ts', 'test/*.ts'],
        tasks: ['typescript:server', 'typescript:test']
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem!

It has been made a [pull request/merge](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/5440) ..

Workaround is to use `angular.mock.module` instead of `module`.

Comment: more than a workaround! the typings definitions for angular-mocks recommends you always use `angular.mock.module`.